How to Integrate Flutter App with Android Auto and Apple CarPlay?
I'm currently working on an existing Flutter mobile application and I'm looking to integrate it with Android Auto and Apple CarPlay. The app features include a GPS navigation system and a list of items. My goal is to make these two features available on Android Auto and Apple CarPlay, while keeping the other functionalities accessible only on the mobile device.
My Questions:

Is it possible to integrate a Flutter application with Android Auto and Apple CarPlay?
If yes, how can I ensure that only specific screens (e.g., GPS and item list) are accessible on these platforms, while other features remain on the phone?

I've done some preliminary research but haven't found clear guidance on how to implement this specifically for Flutter. I'm also interested in any libraries or plugins that might simplify this process.
If anyone has experience or resources on this topic, I'd greatly appreciate your input!
Thank you in advance for your help.

Take a look at this plugin for Apple CarPlay https://github.com/oguzhnatly/flutter_carplay.

Thanks for your reply, by the way, i'm looking for Android Auto too.
